# Multiple monitors with Xubuntu - BIOS Setting missing?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I'm running Xubuntu 14.0.4.2 LTS, and I'm trying to set up a multiple monitor extended desktop. My motherboard has integrated graphics (a VGA soldered on to the motherboard), so I bought a Nvidia GeForce 405 graphics card and a DVI-to-VGA adapter to connect a second monitor.

I can run Xubuntu through the graphics card no problem, but when I connect both monitors (1 to the integrated graphics and one to the Nvidia card), I get a message on start up saying the following.

```
Attention: Unsupported Video Configuration Detected
Action is required
This computer has an add-in graphics card, but the monitor cable is 
plugged into the integrated video connector. To attach the monitor cable to 
the add-in graphics card:
1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug the monitor cable into the add-in graphics card connector. 
3. Turn on the computer.
```

I was doing some more research and I found [this link](https://communities.intel.com/thread/42192). I open my BIOS settings but I cannot find a way to disable the discrete card as the primary graphics device. I'm running a Dell Inspiron 531 with BIOS version 1.0.7.

Please let me know any thoughts you have on this. Do I need to update my BIOS? If so, how can I do this with Xubuntu? Thanks in advance!